# Prevent customers from being deleted in magento

Tags: php, magento

What is the best way to prevent a customer from being deleted in Magento? I want to keep the same functionality but instead of deleting the customer data from the system, it should simply disable their account.

Does Magento offer this functionality out of the box or will i have to write some code?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617832/disable-customer-in-magento

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with this simple extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-activation.html